# prestashop 1.6 - check if user is in group

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

in PS 1.6 I am trying to check if user is in group with id 6 using this:

controller:

```
'hisGroup' => ($this->context->customer->logged AND (Customer::getDefaultGroupId((int)$this->context->customer->id) == 6) ? true : false)
```

tpl:

```
{if $hisGroup}...{/if}
```

although it's not working. Do you have any idea why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you are checked the customer´s default group.
To checked if customer is in a group independently of default group try this

```
'inCustomerGroup' => in_array(4, Customer::getGroupsStatic($this->context->cart->id_customer)) ? true : false,
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is to use {Group::getCurrent()->id}. Tested with prestashop 1.6.+
Hope that help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Try do it that way:

```
$some = $this->context->customer->logged AND (Customer::getDefaultGroupId((int)$this->context->customer->id));
$this->context->smarty->assign('hisGroup', $some);
```

and in tpl:

```
{if $hisGroup == 6} ... {/if}
```